# Usando a Itaucripto_.dll dentro de web service (sem registrar no servidor)

Tags: c#, wcf

Eu tentei colocar a DLL COM no projeto do webservice (usando o código abaixo para incluí-la):

```
<Project ...>
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMFileReference Include="itaucripto_.dll">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMFileReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

É preciso fazer mais algo num serviço WCF com asmx? O servidor levanta uma exceção dizendo que não consegue achar a classe COM porque a mesma não está registrada.
Não desejo registrar a DLL no servidor; mas, em vez disso, quero chamá-la sem registro.
Ambiente:

- Visual Studio 2017
- WCF service application com um web service asmx (estou tentando instanciar no objeto COM no método HelloWorld do asmx)

Código:

```
Itaucripto.cripto itau = new Itaucripto.cripto();
```

Exceção:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
with CLSID {E9067548-B9D1-4146-BEDC-0F7BFEDF6E94} failed due to the 
following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). occurred
```

Comment: Não é uma questão de x64 vs x86? Ex.: Você está compilando o seu projeto em 64 e a dll é 32

Comment: Forcei o projeto para 32bits (x86), nada.

Comment: O problema acontece no debug pelo visual studio ou só quando você publica no IIS?

Comment: Debugando pelo IIS Express no VS.

Comment: Mesmo com plataform target x86 e allow unsafe code marcado?

Comment: Acabei de marcar Unsafe Code. Nada.

Answer (score 0):

Já tive o mesmo problema, encontrei a solução lendo essa pergunta do SO: [interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2483688/4730201)

A solução foi a seguinte:

> ```
> 1. Registrar o assembly de criptografia do Itaú usando o comando REGSVR32 com privilégios de admin. 
>    Exemplo: C:\Windows\System\regsvr32 Itaucripto_.dll
> 2. Importar o assembly no projeto.
> 3. Setar a propriedade "Embed Interop Types" com false na dll importada nas referências, 
>    pois não é uma DLL que roda sobre o Framework .Net
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Nas propriedades do projeto BUILD > General > Marque "Prefer 32-bit"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).